# How can I set an "img src=" to URL in JS variable?

Tags: javascript, html, src

I have an if-else statement which serves up various image URLs depending on the time of day, with one image's URL per "else". I'm hoping I can have an img src where the source loads from that if-else statement, essentially loading a different picture for different times of day.

I have variables set for different times of day, then an if-else statement which selects from those. Below is a minimum reproducible sample:

```
<body onload="load()">
    <p>Test:</p>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4LtRreH.png" id="image" name="image"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
 const now = new Date();
 const slot1 = now.getHours() === 14;
 const slot2 = now.getHours() === 15;

 const imageOne = "https://i.imgur.com/5IaY11U.png";
 const imageTwo = "https://i.imgur.com/ANdRs50.png";

        function load() {
        document.getElementById('image').src= imgPick();
        }

        function imgPick() {
            if (slot1) {
            imageOne;
            } else if (slot2) {
            imageTwo;
            }
        };
</script>

</body>
```

For simplicity, I've just added slots from the time of posting.

My aim is to have my img src in the body be replaced by a URL from my if-else statement. So since I'm posting this at 2:32pm, it should be loading imageOne. Right now, it keeps defaulting to the link given in < body>.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Just add return on `imgPick` method

Comment: On thing to note: you are setting `slot1` and `slot2` when you load the page, and then never again. So if someone loads the page at 13:59, it won't update at 14:00. You may want to update those variables in `imgPick`, depending on your needs, of course.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey - Sorry for my lack of clarity: The lack of other slots is merely evidence of my efforts to minimize the code's footprint in my post. I wanted to omit things to keep it short and sweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the value

```
function imgPick() {
  if (slot1) {
    return imageOne;
  } else if (slot2) {
    return imageTwo;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am a monster at missing the details like this. Anyway, I tested it and it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function imgPick() {

 const now = new Date();
 const slot1 = now.getHours() === 14;
 const slot2 = now.getHours() === 15;

 const imageOne = "https://i.imgur.com/5IaY11U.png";
 const imageTwo = "https://i.imgur.com/ANdRs50.png";

        if (slot1) {
           return imageOne;
        } else if (slot2) {
           return imageTwo;
        }
```

It is better to enter the constants into the function so that once the function is executed they are destroyed and you are not wasting memory while in the global scope.

Comment: I don't see that OP has mentioned TypeScript, so the `:string` will not work. Also, your code will behave differently than OP's. Theirs evaluates the time on pageload, whereas yours will evaluate it on the call of `imgPick`. I agree that it's not great practice to pollute the global scope, but there are likely better ways to solve that while also preserving the existing functionality.

Comment: You're right about :string, I'm sorry, I'm very used to Typescript. How what other ways do you propose?

Comment: No worries! Something like an IIFE would be one way to preserve scope while mitigating global pollution.